# unable to import modules in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I had to install the module 'google', and then because of errors, after reading a SO answer, I had to manually uninstall it. Since then, I am not able to import bs4. It is always giving me the following error:

```
Error processing line 3 of /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googleapis_common_protos-1.5.3-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 174, in addpackage
  exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 568, in module_from_spec
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

Remainder of file ignored
```

I am using Python 3 in ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: My opinion is that your unistall did not finish and something of that google package has been left behind, in your place I would try to move this file : googleapis_common_protos-1.5.3-nspkg.pth out of the way (put it temporarily somewhere else) then if it works delete the file.

Comment: @Marco wow! It isn't giving me any errors! I was uninstalling it manually, so I think I didn't know that these files were part of the google module, so I left them. I'll see if any more errors come, and I can accept an answer if you answer this question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My opinion is that your package unistall did not finish properly and something of that google package has been left behind.

In your place I would try to move this file : googleapis_common_protos-1.5.3-nspkg.pth out of the way (put it temporarily somewhere else) then see if your import module works, in that case delete the file.

Comment: It would be helpful to explain why this works (and why you think it's a safe modification). Thanks!